# Find DIV id content and load through AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Want to load only particular div container contents inside the div container using ajax.

I want to load "ajaxcontainer" contents inside "container" div. It should not load "Test" container.

**HTML:**

```
<a href="javascript:;" data-url="test.html"></a>
<div class="li--menu">
  <ul class="li--choices">
    <li><a href="javascript:;" data-url="test.html">test</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:;" data-url="test1.html">test1</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="container">  </div>
```

**AJAX container HTML**

```
<div id="test" style="width:100%; display: block; border: 1px solid #000; clear:both;">
  Hello World!
</div>

<div id="ajaxContainer">
  test 123
</div>
```

**JS SCRIPT**

```
$('#container').load($('.li--choicesli a').attr('data-url') + '#ajaxContainer');
```

Comment: This should work!! What is happening now??

Comment: There should be a space between URL and `#div` : Notice the space `' #ajaxContainer'`. Example `.load('xyz.html #divID')`

Comment: Thanks... Shaunak.. Yes.. space makes the trick.. But, JavaScript initialization is not working on load.

Comment: document.ready function is not working.. scripts inside this is not working.. Please let me know your comments

Answer (score 0):

Run that for each 'a' element, so that it loads the specified links with matching class. ie

```
$('#container').empty();

$('.li--choicesli a').each(function(){
  $('#container').append($(this).attr('data-url') + '#ajaxContainer');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After adding space before id.. fix the issue

```
$('#container').load($('.li--choicesli a').attr('data-url') + ' #ajaxContainer');
```